# How to upload Big files using NHibernate?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, nhibernate

Problem Statement:

I have a aspx web page which supports file upload (ie. An Attachment).
Attachment can be of size upto 500 MB.
I am able to get the HttpPostedFile But when Reading the stream to Byte[] and saving it to the database fails for bigger size files.
In NHibernateSession.Flush(), Out of Memory exception is thrown.

Note: I am able to upload upto 45MB data.

How to workaround this scenario?

Comment: What database you are using to store that files ?

Comment: Have you considered saving your file to the file system and just save a pointer (filename) in the database?

Comment: No. We should store files only to DB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not use `byte[]` because this means that you will have to load the entire file into memory. Here's a [nice article](http://blog.calyptus.eu/seb/2009/03/large-object-storage-for-nhibernate-and-ddd-part-1-blobs-clobs-and-xlobs/) which illustrates how you could use BLOBS with `Streams` to alleviate those issues. The implementation of the custom Blob data illustrated in the article type could be found [here](http://blog.calyptus.eu/source-code/).

Comment: Would it be indiscreet if I ask why? You have to use a Streaming API, with a byte[] you won't get very far.

Comment: No. Since Nhibrenate is saving blob content from byte[] internally. Can you show me how to achieve this by a snippet.

Comment: @Katturaja, did you read the article I've linked to? It contains many snippets. Try it. If you encounter some specific problems don't hesitate to show your progress and the error you are getting so that we could discuss it.

Comment: I have read the article and I have tried to use those in code. Its not working.

Comment: The code in that repo is hugely incomplete. You should remove this. It wastes people's time.

Answer (score 2):

If your database is MS SQL then you should use [SqlFileStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.sqlfilestream%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). Here is a good [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716724%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) how to do it.